# How will a Canon EOS M serve as a second/alternative body?

Tags: canon, mirrorless, canon-m

With the release of [Canon EOS M](http://www.coolest-gadgets.com/20120724/canon-eos-digital-camera-enters-mirrorless-territory/), the only question I have in mind is how will it perform as a second/alternative/backup body for prefessional/semi-professional photographers? We can use our existing EF mount lenses, also the sensor is APS-C sized. Will it provide better optical performance than Canon G11/G12 or G series cameras in general? Also how does it compare to people who uses FF mainly but have APS-C DSLRs as an alternative body.

Comment: Small comment: the EOS M has an EF-M mount, and will not mount EF mount lenses without the EF-M adapter for EF (currently $200 USD).

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, but thanks for pointing it out loud. Being able to use all my existing lenses at the price of 200$ sounds great to me.

Comment: I think this question needs to be much more specific. What type of photography do you do? What needs do you have for a backup body? Is this as a backup for a professional wedding photographer in the field, or a backup for an amateur at a childs soccer game? Do you currently use full frame or APS-C? You are trying to compare the EOS M to literally every existing Canon camera user as the question sits now, and it is too broad I think to be useful to anybody.

Comment: If it is a backup body, why wouldn't you just buy a Canon 650D/T4i or something similar. I don't know of any professionals that would go with anything below this for a backup body. Most use an older version of the current body they use, such as a 5D Mk 1 or even a 7D.

Comment: Actually that's what the question is for. People tend to use mostly EOS XXXD, XXD or XD as backups. A few people I have seen even uses G11. I am not asking for a comparison to every existing cameras, rather, what I am asking is whether this EOS-M series can be considered as a backup body at all? If yes, why and if not, why.

Comment: If that is the case, I would alter your question to say "...perform as a backup body..." and remove the references to a second body or alternative body. A backup is not the same as a alternative body, at least to me. My iPhone serves as my alternative body, but does not serve as my backup when shooting a wedding. As far as comparing to every camera that exists, I think this question would be more beneficial if you mentioned what your main camera was, a 7D, a 5D, etc. The comparison to full frame against the EOS M and the comparison to a 7D against the EOS M is completely different.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The EOS M has essentially the same image pipeline (sensor / image processor) as the latest digital rebel. You can therefore expect it to produce very high quality images considering the form factor (though not necessarily any better than the competition mirrorless). Image quality should be better than the G series, though similar to the G1X (which has a slightly smaller sensor, but has a lens optimised for that sensor).

The option to produce DSLR quality images will obviously be attractive to those looking for a backup camera to bring abroad or on remote shoots however there are a few factors to be aware of:

- Autofocus. Performance with regular EF lenses wont be good as the M mount glass. You can expect it to be similar to using liveview AF on the 650D, not as quick as a dedicated phase detection sensor.
- Viewfinder. There isn't one, which will make shooting in bright sunlight difficult.
- Manual controls. Also lacking, changing shutter speed / aperture / ISO will all involve taking your eye of the ball and using the rear touchscreen.

Finally there's the price which puts it on a par with the 650D. I think you would have to be seriously concerned about size to forgo the viewfinder and phase detect AF. Replacing your backup rebel with an EOS M will result your camera bag being **277 grams lighter**. If you have a couple of lenses in there already you're unlikely to notice.  The space saving is slightly more being about 35% of the volume of a rebel. You might be able to sneak an extra (small) lens into your bag.

The other potential advantage to the M is to use where you don't want to draw unnecessary attention to yourself, or to take photos where "professional cameras" are not allowed (you'll just have to find some other way to disguise your 400 f/2.8)

Comment: The reality is, the biggest _advantage_ of this camera is its small size. How important is size to my backup camera? It isn't even on my list. I would consider it to be a detriment in this case as the camera is too small to be comfortable for extended use.

Answer (score 9):

The Canon EOS M stands virtually no chance of being a professionally used backup body and I speak strictly in the sense of professional event photography.

The EOS M is certainly an advancement for the compact size yet great quality department, but it simply does not have the demanding feature set that is required in any professional capability. Some significant cons to using the EOS M in a professional capacity include:

- Lack of weather sealing
- Lack of dedicated physical controls for things like mode
- Small button size of existing buttons is not very friendly to utilize while camera is being composed(up to face).
- Lack of viewfinder, which also affects battery life
- This might be ill advice, but the camera simply does not look professional. It comes in red. If you are comfortable charging someone to shoot an event and you show up with a red camera the size of an Android phone, that is your decision but I would not do so.
- The body is *too small*. I'm not going to connect a full size Canon 580EX to this and walk around with a 70-200mm IS lens(with adapter). Even the Rebel series cameras are uncomfortable for this, so this would be horrid.

Using the Canon M does have some advantages. It is small in size(*can* be an advantage), can utilize existing EF and EF-S lenses with an adapter, should be quite quiet at shooting, and the price is reasonable.

As I mentioned in a comment elsewhere here, I think that the Canon EOS M's biggest advantage is it's size. It isn't really cheap, it isn't really the *best* quality(think AF and APS-C), and it isn't full of the most professional features. So why would you choose this as a backup camera? For it's great size advantage? I really don't think so. 
The only use case I can think of is someone who does a significant amount of destination weddings, where you have to worry about the portability and size of your kit on a whole new level.

Overall, I don't know of any professional that would carry a Canon G11 or a S100 in their bag and consider it a backup, and I don't see that happening with this either just because they can now use the full range of EF lenses. If you are using this as a backup for PERSONAL use, certainly it will capture images and fit the majority of use cases for personal use.

Comment: +1 for the lack of a mode dial. You can get that in many comparably priced semipro P&Ses like the Panasonic DMC-LXn series. (Or Canon's own G series for that matter.)

Comment: Re: Canon EF-M vs. the G series as an SLR backup, there are some serious points in favor of the EF-M. The bigger sensor will allow shallower DoF and probably less noise at a given ISO. Lens interchangeability lets you get a wider AoV range, with better glass, though only by throwing away portability. Still, for the stated goal, I think I'd rather have a Rebel. The EF-M really only makes sense to me with the EF-M dedicated lenses, at which point I wonder why I'm sticking with Canon. Might as well go with a micro 4/3 camera, and get a wider lens selection.

Comment: @WarrenYoung - It has a mode dial, but only contains 3 positions, two of which I would rarely use. I would much prefer it to offer the standard scene modes of M, Tv, Av, B, P, etc.

Comment: True, the Canon GX1 only has a 20% smaller sensor, but yes it is smaller.